# what is the proplem with my code?

Tags: php

Please tell me my error.

The errors are:

> Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp\www\3arabschool\admin\section_insert.php on line 10

Source code is here:

```
<?php
include("../config/config.php");


if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = addslashes($_POST['name']); }
if(isset($_POST['order_sec'])){ $order_sec = addslashes($_POST['order_sec']); }
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){ $sub = $_POST['sub']; }


if ($name == ""){   // this is line 10
echo "<div align='center'>please enter name<ahref='javascript:history.back(1)'>back</a></div>";
}else{
$query = @mysqli_query ($con,"INSERT INTO article_sec (name,sub,order_sec)VALUES ('$name','$sub','$order_sec')") or die ("error query");
echo "<p align='center'>done</p>";
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='1' URL='section.php'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you read the notice text? `Undefined variable: name` <-- that's it. It's undefined

Comment: what is the solution.

Comment: just don't try to access undefined variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing a variable that isn't defined unless `$_POST['name']` has been defined.

Change the line

```
if ($name == ""){
```

to

```
if (empty($name)) {
```

PHP will check to see if the variable is set before trying to access it and see if it's empty using this function. [See this doc for more info](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: ok..thanks now he asked me to enter name and i fill the form can you help in it.

Comment: @user3769561 I don't understand what you're asking, but since this has solved your problem please mark my answer as accepted and make a new question for your new problem (assuming you did enough due diligence to research the new problem on your own)

Answer (score 0):

Probably isset() is returning false when you check the `$_POST` array for your index. Thus, `$name` is never being defined. To make sure it's defined, initialize it to something, maybe `$name = '';` before the check.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your `if` statement is failing and hence `$name` never gets declared/defined. To solve it you can use:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{ 
   $name = addslashes($_POST['name']); 
} 
else // making sure $name gets declared if the above condition fails
{ 
   $name = ''; 
}
```

OR change

```
if ($name == "")
```

to

```
if(! isset($name))
```